# Why does the keyword range in golang work for 2d-slices?

Tags: go, slice

I'd like to make a copy of a slice of bytes, convert the type from `[][4]byte` to `[][]byte`. And I expect the followering code to return `[[1 2 3 4] [2 3 4 5]]`, but actually got `[[2 3 4 5] [2 3 4 5]]`.

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    ids := [][4]byte{[4]byte{1, 2, 3, 4}, [4]byte{2, 3, 4, 5}}

    var slices [][]byte
    for _, id := range ids {
        slices = append(slices, id[:])
    }
    fmt.Println(slices)
}
```

Why?

Why appending `id[:]` to the slice would overwrite the first element in the slice?

Comment: Please read https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/CommonMistakes#using-reference-to-loop-iterator-variable, then try `for i := range ids {
slices = append(slices, ids[i][:]) }`

Answer (score 1):

As said by Marc, you are appending a reference via id.

Therefore when you iterate, and id changes its value, your "slices" to which you are appending are getting re-evaluated with id new values.

To avoid this:

```
for i := range ids { 
     slices = append(slices, ids[i][:]) // here you are referring to the value at index i of ids
}
```